# How do I draw a line without updating the whole screen in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a visual representation that includes a moving line and a static background. Is there a way to visualize the moving line without having to update the whole screen? I am aware of `pygame.display.flip()` but that would require the program to "blit" the background in each frame, which I want to avoid.

I have been trying to create a rect object for the background and one for the line, and then do `pygame.display.update(line_rect)` but I couldn't figure a way to include a line in a rect.

All ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a line that is defined by the points (`x1`, `y1`) and (`x2`, `y2`), the bounding rectangle can be computed with `min` and `max`:

```py
min_x, min_y = min(x1, x2), min(y1, y2)
max_x, max_y = max(x1, x2), max(y1, y2)
line_rect = pygame.Rect(min_x, min_y, max_x-min_x, max_y-min_y)
```

Alternatively you can join two rectangles with the size 1x1 with [`union`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.union) to one that completely covers the area of the two provided rectangles:

```py
line_rect = pygame.Rect(x1, y1, 1, 1).union((x2, y2, 1, 1))
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

center_x, center_y = window.get_rect().center
radius = 100
line_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(1, 0)
angle = 0
prev_line_rect = None

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window_center = window.get_rect().center

    rot_vector = line_vector.rotate(angle) * radius
    x1, y1 = round(center_x + rot_vector.x), round(center_y + rot_vector.y)
    x2, y2 = round(center_x - rot_vector.x), round(center_y - rot_vector.y)
    angle += 1

    line_rect = pygame.Rect(x1, y1, 1, 1).union((x2, y2, 1, 1))
    
    copy_rect = line_rect.copy()
    if prev_line_rect:
        line_rect.union_ip(prev_line_rect)
        line_rect.inflate_ip(2, 2)
    prev_line_rect = copy_rect

    window.fill(0, line_rect)
    pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 255, 255), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), 3)

    pygame.display.update(line_rect)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your time and effort. Correct me if I am wrong, I hope I am getting this right. Let's say I want to add a different color (or an image) for the background, as black is the default. I would have to do ```window.fill(COLOR, line_rect)``` or blit the image. Neither of these work: the former only fills with color the region in which the line is rotating and the latter requires ```pygame.display.flip()``` to make the image show. Could I do either of the above by modifying your code in a different way?

Comment: @BillTheKid I've no idea what you mean. I it hard to guess your intention because you haven't provided any code. I cannot guess your bugs. You have to redraw the entire region which is covered by the update region. Anyway, it is common this days to redraw the entire scene in every frame. It is "cheaper" to redraw the entire scene, than to manage update sub-regions

Comment: Perhaps I had misunderstood the way Rect works. It might not be possible to do what I am thinking of doing. If you want to recreate my last "bug", replace `window.fill(0, line_rect)` with `window.fill(100, line_rect`. I would expect that change to fill the whole screen with blue color but it just draws a circle. Anyway, thank you again for your time and effort, you have already taught me some things. I'll try to find a different way to get around my problem.

Comment: @BillTheKid It works absolut correctly. It appears to be a circle. In each frame a rectangular region is updated, that covers the line. If you stack all this regions you get a circle. The rectangular area changes in every frame. Why do you not see that?

Comment: It does exactly what it is supposed to do. But I did not want it do that. That's why I misunderstood the way `pygame.Rect` works. I don't want the background to change, I just want the line itself. but the line exists on the background so it changes it.

Comment: @BillTheKid That is not possible. The entire region is redrawn. Of course you can completely skip `window.fill(0, line_rect)` completely, but then the lines from all previous frames stay there and you just draw on a line on top of each other. You can't magically let disappear the line of the previous frame. All that is drawn is just a bunch of pixels on a _Surface_. A pixel has just a color. When something is drawn on top, the previous color is lost forever.

Comment: If you use a solid background, one approach is to redraw the previous line in the background color, then draw the new line in the foreground color.  (Effectively "erasing" the pixels the previous line had written to.)

Comment: @RufusVS Thanks for the idea, though I am using a "complex" background.